# how to SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING and REPLACE?

Tags: sql, casting, google-bigquery

i got a table with three columns whose type is BYTES
i succeed to make a SELECT SAFE_CONVERT_BYTES_TO_STRING
but now, i wish i could REPLACE my BYTES values by their corresponding STRING in my original table

Comment: Please post an example of any code you have or have tried, as well as sample inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the value would imply changing the column type, which is [not supported](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas).

My recommendation would be to save your query results to a different [destination table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/writing-results#permanent-table) then [drop the current table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#deleting_tables) and [copy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#copy-table) the destination table to rename it as the original one.